# Dealing with one KeyError best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I have shortend the script and the start date of `pendulum` to reproduce this error more quickly. When the start date was `2016, 4, 2` I got through around 47,661 returned results before this `KeyError` occurred. To my knowledge I could use a `try:` `except` to pass up the `KeyError`. However I would not know any other KeyErrors that may come up after that point and that seems like I am just (for lack of a better word) "swallowing" my errors. What is best practice for this 1 in 50,000 (so far) occurrance.

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum

gamepks = set()

start = pendulum.datetime(2016, 5, 18)
end = pendulum.datetime(2016, 10, 2)
period = pendulum.period(start, end)

for dt in period.range('days'):
        day = dt.format('DD')
        month = dt.format('MM')
        year = dt.format('YYYY')
        the_date = str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year) 

        try:
            req = requests.get('http://gd.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_' + str(year) + '/month_' + str(month) + '/day_' + str(day) + '/miniscoreboard.json') # 
            get_gameIds = req.json()['data']['games']['game']

            for gameId in get_gameIds:
                gamepk = gameId['game_pk']
                gamepks.add(gamepk)            
        except(KeyError,TypeError):
            pass

for new_pk in sorted(gamepks):

    req = requests.get('https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1.1/game/' + str(new_pk) + '/feed/live?language=en') # ' + str(gamepk) + ' 530302
    at_bat_log = req.json()['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']

    # Get Game date

    game_data = req.json()['gameData']
    gamedate = game_data['datetime']['originalDate']

    # GET PARK & TEAMS

    teams = game_data['teams']
    home_team = teams['home']
    park = home_team['abbreviation']
    away = teams['away']['abbreviation']
    home = home_team['abbreviation']
    batter_team = (away,home)
    pitcher_team = (home,away)

    for keys in at_bat_log:
        result = keys['result']
        res_type = result['type']
        res_event = result['event']
        des = result['description']
        rbi = result['rbi']
        about = keys['about']
        topbot = about['halfInning']

        if topbot == "bottom":
            topbot = "B"
        if topbot == "top":
            topbot = "T"

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "C:/Python36/Projects/Shoretend_for_testing_CODE.py", line 65, in <module>
#    inn = about['inning']
#  KeyError: 'inning'

        inn = about['inning']
        inning = str(topbot) + str(inn)

        row = [new_pk, inning]
        print(row)
```

Comment: "I would not know any other KeyErrors that make come up after that point" - no, you definitely would, as long as you don't exit the loop in the `except` clause.

Comment: First point: you didn't post the traceback nor specified where exactly this KeyError occurs (which line). Second point: in your first loop, the try/except clause is too large (too many statements in the `try` block). Third point: you should _at least_ print out the exception (and relevant data, ie the date) in the `except` clause so you have a clue about what happens.

Comment: First point the error is commented out in the script. Second point is that first try is for skipping over dates without games. That First try has no barring on the latter

Comment: @ForceBru How would I still continue through the script after that point and still be prompted for further errors

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson, just wrap the offending lines _inside the loop_ in a `try/except` clause like this: `try: <might raise something> except KeyError: continue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `.get` method on dictionaries. so, instead of doing `keys['about']`, use   `keys.get("about", "DEFAULT_VALUE")`.
 so, if key exists, you will get the value, else you will get default value which is the second argument in the get method

Comment: Thanks! This way I can make them stand out.